# Is it possible to import text from an online .txt file to Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import texts from ads.txt files from a certain websites to Gsheets. I try Importxml however it states that the important xml content can not be parsed.

example:
I'm trying to import text from this file --> financhill.com/ads.txt

I'm using this code =IMPORTXML("https://financhill.com/ads.txt","/html/body/pre/text()")

the result is N/A **important xml content can not be parsed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the data from the URL, it seems that the data is the CSV data. I think that this is the reason of your issue of `the result is N/A important xml content can not be parsed.`. In this case, how about using `IMPORTDATA` as follows?

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://financhill.com/ads.txt")
```

and

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://financhill.com/ads.txt",",")
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTDATA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335)